# Setting a variable in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

My first question here or even my first try at making a script.

I have a file named "test PID 1100 DELAY 1100ms.acc" and i can output the name of the file in command line using :-

```
for %i in (test*.aac) do echo %~ni
```

However in the script when i put it like this :-

```
SET AACFILE=for %i in (test*.aac) do echo %~ni
D:\Converter\bin\faad.exe -o C:\fb\test.wav "C:\fb\%AACFILE%.aac"
```

It does not output the filename with below error :-

```
c:\fb>aactowav.bat
c:\fb>SET "AACFILE=for ~ni"
c:\fb>D:\Converter\bin\faad.exe -o C:\fb\test.wav C:\fb\for ~ni.aac
 *********** Ahead Software MPEG-4 AAC Decoder V2.7 ******************
 Build: Oct 27 2012
 Copyright 2002-2004: Ahead Software AG
 http://www.audiocoding.com
 Floating point version
 This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 it under the terms of the GNU General Public License.

 **************************************************************************

 Error opening file: C:\fb\for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line sets the variable to the last filename that matches the filespec:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (test*.aac) do SET "AACFILE=%%~ni"
echo "%aacfile%"
```

Comment: I have another related question, not sure if i should ask here or open a new one.

How can i grab the value in ms from the filename, for example from this file "test PID 1100 DELAY 1100ms.acc" I want the script to read "1100ms" and then add 100 to it and display ?

Comment: I'd recommend just asking a new question.